# For a compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$ not separating $0$ from $\infty$, is there a simply connected region containing it that doesn't contain $0$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

A compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$ that does not separate $0$ from $\infty$ is one in which $0$ lies in the unique unbounded component of its complement.

A region refers to a connected open subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

CONTEXT: In an unital complex Banach algebra, a condition for an element $x$ to have a logarithm (i.e. another element $z$ such that $\exp(z)=x$) is that the spectrum $\sigma(x)$ of $x$ doesn't separate $0$ from $\infty$. The proof in *Functional Analysis* by Walter Rudin (theorem 10.30) requires a simply connected region $\Omega\supset\sigma(x)$ and a holomorphism $f\in H(\Omega)$ such that $\exp(f(\lambda))=\lambda\;(\forall\lambda\in\Omega)$, which means $0\notin\Omega$. By the theory of complex analysis, the condition "simply connected" ensures the existence of $f$. But Rudin did not prove the existence of $\Omega$.

By hypothesis, there's a continuously differentiable curve $p:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ from $0$ to $\infty$ such that $p(t_1)=p(t_2)\Rightarrow t_1=t_2$ and $p([0,\infty))\cap\sigma(x)=\emptyset$. Choose positive numbers $r_1<\operatorname{d}(0,\sigma(x))$ and $r_2>\|x\|$. Define the annulus $A\triangleq\{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}\mid r_1<\|\lambda\|<r_2\}$, $v$ to be the minimal number such that $\|p(v)\|=r_2$ and $u$ to be the maximal number less than $v$ such that $\|p(u)\|=r_1$. I guess $A\setminus p([u,v])$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^1\setminus\{*\}$ but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: I don't understand $\lneq$ and $\operatorname{diam}$ in "$r_1\lneq \operatorname{diam}(0,\sigma(x))$". Do you mean $r_1<d(0,\sigma(x))$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some general theorems that can let you avoid getting your hands dirty here.  The image of your path $p$ together with $\infty$ is a subset $P\subset\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$ homeomorphic to $[0,1]$.  Then, by [Alexander duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_duality), the reduced homology of $\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}\setminus P$ is trivial.  This then implies there is a holomorphic logarithm on $\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}\setminus P$ (by integrating $1/z$ along any path, which is well-defined since all loops are nullhomologous).

(In fact, more strongly, $\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}\setminus P$ is simply connected.  This follows, for instance, from the Riemann mapping theorem, whose proof uses only that $H_1$ is trivial and not actually that $\pi_1$ is trivial, since it only ever uses this for the purposes of integration.)